# Adding Custom Tabs in Product Detail Page

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, tabs

I have created an attribute with "Product Details" as Textarea in admin panel.

Now I need to make it display as "Product Details" next to description tab in product detail page for each and every product.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: Can you please show catalog.xml code thus i can check

Comment: which theme you use? which version of magento? are u using easytabs extension or u r using ur custom theme?

Comment: <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="Description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                </block>

Comment: I am using SNS Toronto and not using any extensions. Magento version is 1.9.1

Comment: I want to add a tab similar to what Description does.

Comment: Hey If you are using custom theme then it will be depends on purchase theme how they can manage but if you are using the default magento theme the I can help you

Comment: oh. Can you please help me with the default magento theme? So that i will try it embedding in my theme.

Comment: @Raj Might I suggest considering changing the accepted answer, as it does not follow upgrade compatible practices for Magento.

Comment: @Meogi Are you saying that when i upgrade my version i need to rework again in this section?

Comment: @Raj I'm stating that if you upgrade your version, and Magento's core team made updates to "catalog.xml", your site will not receive those updates since you have copied it to your local theme. All layout updates should be done in local.xml. I found this out the hard way when I upgraded an older Magento site of mine and had done the very same thing. Magento's core development team had made updates to the Catalog module's "catalog.xml" file, and because I had copied this to my local theme, those updates did not apply. It took me several hours to track down why errors were occurring.

Comment: @Raj Or, if you just edit "catalog.xml" directly (or any other `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/*xml` files, or `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/*.xml` files...) without having copied them to your local theme. Then upgrading Magento will OVERWRITE all your changes to those files. Therefore, either way, people should avoid editing these files. There is nothing that cannot be edited/added to/removed with proper instructions in your own layout file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add this code after `Description` block in `catalog.xml` files

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="Your_attribute_name" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Your tab name</value></action>
 </block>
```

you can add in the above way for any number of tabs needed hope this helps.

Comment: @dh47 catalog.xml should not be edited directly, this should go in local.xml

Comment: @Meogi we can edit `catalog.xml` in theme's layout ofcourse yes editing in `local.xml` is best thing forever.

Comment: @dh47 Yes you "can" edit it these files however you're asking for upgrade issues by editing any `app/design/frontend/*/default/layout/*.xml` files. By copying these files from base/default or rwd/default to you're local theme you are losing ALL upgrade instructions from an ENTIRE core module when you perform Magento upgrades. If this is what you're looking for then edit away. There isn't anything in these files that cannot be appended to / modified / removed with instructions from local.xml.

Comment: @dh47 Unknowingly did it. Recasting my vote.

Comment: Also see the comment @Meogi posted

Answer (score 4):

Create the file `app/frontend/design/{packageName}/{themeName}/layout/local.xml` if it does not exist already.

**Note:** *{packageName}* is most likely "default" or "rwd", depending on your site setup. *{themeName}* should be a folder you created to use as the theme for your site, which extends the "default" theme.

In that local.xml file, include the following: (If this file already exists for you, just add the contents within the 'catalog_product_view' layout handle).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product_details" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Product Details</value></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```