# How to create a custom tab in product details page?

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog

In magento 1.9.2.4 Product details page, I want to keep a `tab` to switch between contents like below:

[image]

But already In details page there is default tab (I inherited rwd theme) Like this:
[image]
In `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

coding for this tab was like this:

```
<div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
    <?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
        <dl id="collateral-tabs" class="collateral-tabs">
            <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $alias => $html):?>
                <dt class="tab"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getChildData($alias, 'title')) ?></span></dt>
                <dd class="tab-container">
                    <div class="tab-content"><?php echo $html ?></div>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </dl>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

And in `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/layout/catalog.xml`
 it was like this:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml"> 
     <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
     <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Description</value></action>
</block>
```

so In order to keep like this tab I added this code in phtml file:

```
<div class="details-tab">
<div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
    <?php if ($miniDetailedInfoGroup = $this->getChildGroup('detail_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
        <dl id="collateral-tabs" class="collateral-tabs">
            <?php foreach ($miniDetailedInfoGroup as $alias => $html):?>
                <dt class="tab"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getChildData($alias, 'title')) ?></span></dt>
                <dd class="tab-container">
                    <div class="tab-content"><?php echo $html ?></div>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </dl>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>
```

and added in xml file like this:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml"> 
     <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detail_info</group></action>
     <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Description</value></action>
</block>
```

But nothing displayed. Someone please help.

Comment: What exactly you want to do ? add tab ? rename tab ? reorder tabs ?

Comment: I want to add a new tab like first image mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add your new tab like this in your `catalog.xml`

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml" >
         .........
         other tabs

         <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>your_name</alias><title>Your Tab Name</title><block>catalog/product_view_description</block><template>catalog/product/view/your_file.phtml</template></action>
         ................
         other stuff
</block>
```

if you wish to add from your `local.xml` then have this instead:

```
<reference name="product.info.tabs">
     <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>your_name</alias><title>Your Tab Name</title><block>catalog/product_view_description</block><template>catalog/product/view/your_file.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

If you look at `<block>` node `catalog/product_view_description`, means you are calling `mage/catalog/product/view/description.php` block. If you want to call your own you can change this.

And obviously your phtml file is `your_file.phtml` with your own content.

Comment: I dont find  block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" in catalog.xml

Comment: It should be inside `<catalog_product_view>` node.

Comment: sorry it is not found there.

Comment: If you have fresh magento version then this would be there. Not sure if it is in your local.xml instead.

Comment: I have fresh magento 1.9.2.4. And I dont have any  local.xml

Comment: If that's the case, then you can add it inside `content` part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39715/discussion-between-ramya-and-adarsh-khatri).

Comment: are you saying about magento CE?

Comment: you only need to create local.xml...its a custom file used to put our custom code..

Answer (score 1):

You are very close to the solution in your code.

For this you need to follow the following steps.

either create a local.xml file in layout directory and place a following code into it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="module.data" as="test" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Description</value></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

**OR**

1) Create your custom module.

2) Define a block which extends `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract`.

3) either create a layout file for your module or use local.xml. if  local.xml not exist then you have to create it in layout directory and place the following code in layout file.Please make changes in as per your class group in config file. in my case it is  **comp_faq**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="comp_faq/list" name="comp.faq" as="compfaq" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Descriptionaaaa</value></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

4) code for block file .

```
class Comp_Faq_Block_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{

}
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: Can I not create a new tab without creating custom module??

Comment: update the answer please check

Comment: I dont need a tab to be added to p`ParentGroup`. I want to create new frensh tab element. Please guid me regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question worked for us:

[Adding Custom Tabs in Product Detail Page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51649/adding-custom-tabs-in-product-detail-page)

Just please read the comments first and edit local.xml file instead of catalog.XML like suggested there. It works, but its bad practice.