# How to find file to customize content in product long description in magento 1.9.3

Tags: magento-1.9, product-page

I am working on a project in which I will be adding product description in a tabular format to the product specification. But I could not find the file responsible.

I am using default Magento Theme. I am able to find the product page at `app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml` but **it doesn't contain any code for making changes in the Long description of the product**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding Custom Tabs in Product Detail Page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51649/adding-custom-tabs-in-product-detail-page)

Comment: Not necessarily a duplicate of that question as that question is about how to add a tab and this question is about where to find the long description...

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is literally "how to find the file", the short answer is: Use template hints.

1. Log into the Magento admin
2. Go to System -> Configuration in the main menu
3. Go to Developer on the bottom left under ADVANCED
4. Switch to the store view on the top left to your current website or store view.
5. Under the Debug tab of the same Developer config page you will see a new option appear that will allow you to turn on/off template path hints.

*Remember to clear your cache.*
Disclaimer: The above steps are copy/pasted from [this article](http://support.magerewards.com/article/1534-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints).

To achieve what you're wanting to do, you'll need basically two things:

1. Your own phtml template file, which `echo`s the data you want to show, and...
2. Some layout XML which tells Magento what phtml template and php block class to use for your tab.

These SE answers explain in more detail:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/52381/15970
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26557947/884734

Also this Atwix article could be a good resource: https://www.atwix.com/magento/adding-tabs-on-the-product-page/